# PDF not showed correctly in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, pdf, sdk, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in which I want to display a PDF file. The PDF file is located on a remote webserver and is therefore loaded like any other URL.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.findsmiley.fvst.dk/KontrolRapport.aspx?id=20328832&akt=1"]]];
```

The PDF is not displayed correctly, though. I am not able to scroll or zoom the document.
In the console I get the following error codes (*CafeHelmuth* being the name of my application, of course)

```
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Wed Mar 23 15:56:31 simonbs-macbook CafeHelmuth[1997] <Error>: 
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

On the image below you see that it does not scroll the web page but the view, which, of course, is wrong.

Can anyone please help me make my web view display the PDF document correctly?

[image: UIWebView not scroll webpage]

Adding `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;` before `loadRequest` makes it look a bit strange, though it does add zoom and scroll but it does not seem to be the right approach. Beneath are some images of this.

[image: When zoomed out]

When I zoom in the background becomes blue and.. Well, it looks strange.

[image: When zoomed in]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

before the loadRequest line

Comment: This looks a bit weird for A4 paper format, but yes at least it can be zoomed.

Comment: I just tried doing so. This makes it look very strange. Check my first post for images.

Comment: I've had a look at what actually gets downloaded from your URL and it is not simply a pdf file -- it's a lot of javascript which does complicated things with the screen layout before loading the pdf file.  If you can just download the pdf file this should be OK. Otherwise you will have to change the javascript so it runs the way you want it in the webview (I can't help you there)

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait a month. That's right. I will take a look into that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution to customize the behaviour of the webview. But I have found a solution for your pdf: Change the pdf's format to 10.7 cm x 15.7 cm. Have a look at this example: [image: pdf example in webview]

Comment: Is this possible when loaded from the web? Do you know any way to do this when the PDF is loaded from the web?

Comment: Sorry I don't know of any way. The main problem you will encounter in case you manage to change paper sizes on the fly, that the whole layout may burst. It's like having an iPhone version of the pdf.

Comment: Oh, that's not really the purpose. I find it strange that it should be so hard to show a PDF in a UIWebView when Apples own Safari does it nicely.

Comment: I hope that there is an easy way but I haven't found one yet.